# Why weren't J.A.R.V.I.S. & Jarvis played by the same actor in MCU?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, casting, iron-man, agent-carter

J.A.R.V.I.S. is the AI built by Tony Stark as an aid & house-help (Butler) based on Jarvis who was the aid & house-help (Butler) of Howard Stark, Tony's father.

J.A.R.V.I.S. is voiced by Paul Bettany & Jarvis is played by James D'Arcy.

Iron Man came out first & then a few years later, Agent Carter came out.

So the question can be either why Paul Bettany, who voiced J.A.R.V.I.S., didn't play Jarvis in Agent Carter or why James D'Arcy didn't voice J.A.R.V.I.S. in Iron Man & subsequent films.

Their (Jarvis's) mannerisms are very similar so from a sense of continuity why didn't MCU producers hire the same actor to play both roles. A word from producers would be great.

Comment: I'd like to point something else here. In question title it says **Why weren't J.A.R.V.I.S. & Jarvis played by the same actor in MCU?** Jarvis was not in MCU. J.A.R.V.I.S is

Comment: @Vishwa Agent Carter & Agents of SHIELD are directly in MCU. Other Marvel TV shows are indirectly in MCU

Comment: Oh.. Agent Carter was so boring (other than Hayley Atwell), I seriously thought It may've been spitted out from MCU

Comment: This question border on topics that are off-topic. Notably rules `there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”` and `you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”`. Your question boils down to "why didn't they do this thing I thought they could maybe do?". There is no actual link between Jarvis and J.A.R.V.I.S, there is no reason why one should look like the other.

Comment: @Flater Tony Stark based JARVIS on Jarvis. Hence he named it JARVIS. So there is a connection between the two

Comment: @KharoBangdo: That doesn't mean that they must therefore look or sound the same. That is my point. You're trying to extend the story beyond what it actually is, and that's not on topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was cleared in tie-in comics [Iron Man 2: Public Identity](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Man_2:_Public_Identity), that J.A.R.V.I.S. is inspired by Jarvis. But hiring a Movie actor for a TV show is not so easy. When Paul Bettany signed for Iron Man films, Agent Carter was not even planned. So Paul was not obliged to play human Jarvis. And TV show don't spend as much as a big blockbuster like Iron Man do.

Here is what D'Arcy said:

> "Other than the obvious fact that the J.A.R.V.I.S. system in the Iron Man suit is based on Tony's memory of who Jarvis was -- or maybe his invention of how he wishes Jarvis was -- it's not even clear if that's for real. He doesn't have to be the real person," D'Arcy said. "It gave us enormous freedom to explore the real-life Jarvis in whatever way we wanted." - [IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/01/29/agent-carter-james-darcy-asks-did-tony-stark-actually-know-edwin-jarvis)

Answer (score 0):

It's because Tony made the AI J.A.R.V.I.S like he remembers Jarvis as a person to do anything for him (butler) or like he wanted him to be. But he hasn't met Jarvis because he died when Tony was just a little baby.

So J.A.R.V.I.S./Vision is not the same actor because Tony doesn't quite remember Jarvis.
And Iron Man was made before Agent Carter even started so James d'Arcy couldn't be Vision even if he wanted To.

Answer (score -1):

Tony wasn't alive when human Edwin Jarvis was, and he created the JARVIS AI, so the result came out differently. Then, when JARVIS becomes Vision, we first see the human form of Vision in Infinity War and he looks like Paul Bettany; This was probably more out of convenience than anything else since he had been cast since Iron Man 1, plus it would've been weird if he looked like a different actor with Paul Bettany's voice coming out of them.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything new to the existing answers.